# How slice method works in JavaScript?

Tags: forms, button, input

I want to know how **slice(0, -1)** working in a calculator? Made by html, CSS and JavaScript. It is working fine. But i don't know how it deleting the numbers one by one every single time I click the button.

**slice(0, -1) ** working fine.
But i don't know how it works. I am expecting to explain the code for better undestand.

Answer (score 0):

The Slice() method in java script is used to extract a portion of string or array and return it as a new string or array. it takes 2 arguments.
slice("Start-index","End index"), The end-index here is optional, if the end index is not given it will slice the string or array till end.

example:

```
string test = "hello";
string result = test.slice(0,4); // excludes 4th char that is 'o'
**output: hell**
```

How slice(0,-1) used in calculator:
This slice(0,-1) is commonly used in calculator to slice the last character of the input string. Here the 0 indicates that the slicing should start from the beginning and -1 indicates that the we want to stop one char before the end of string or array. For example, let's say the current input string in the calculator is "12345". When the "backspace" button is clicked, the following code is executed:

```
let inputString = "12345";
inputString = inputString.slice(0, -1);
console.log(inputString); // "1234"
```

As you see, it removes the last char of the input string.so everytime you click on backspace this following code is executed and the last char is removed.

Answer (score -2):

The `slice(0, -1)` method can be used to delete the last character from a string, which in this case represents the current value displayed on the calculator screen.

When a user clicks a button on the calculator, the corresponding button value is added to the current value displayed on the calculator screen. For example, if the user clicks the <kbd>1</kbd> button, the digit `1` is added to the current value displayed on the calculator screen.

When the user clicks the <kbd>delete</kbd> button, the `slice(0, -1)` method is called on the current value displayed on the calculator screen. The slice method is used to extract a substring from the string, starting from index 0 and ending at index -1, which represents the last character in the string. Since the end index is negative, it counts from the end of the string.

In effect, the `slice(0, -1)` method removes the last character from the string, which is the character that was just added by the previous button click. This is how the calculator is able to delete the last digit or operator that was entered by the user.